# Why do only certain font switches work in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, formatting

If my codes have a statement like `${\bfseries{\emph{something}}$`, it will return an error:

> \bfseries invalid in math code.

But if I change the order of the control sequences, like this `${\emph{\bfseries{something}}$`, everything is fine. Why is that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: Why don't you use `$\textbf{...}$`?

Comment: @JouleV.Yeah,I also know that key word, but it only works in English.

Comment: Did you use a language other than English? If so, did you use `babel`? Or did you use `xeCJK`?

Comment: if `something` is word in text, than omit `$`, if it is math expression, than write `$\mathbf{something}$`. for more help you should provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass ...` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: $\mathbf{something}$and    $\textbf{...}$both make sense, but I want the 
   something to have both black and italic styles.I'm curious about the order in which keywords are used can affect the success of code compilation, especially to these trivial keywords. Is this phenomenon common?@Zarko

Comment: If you want to mark something bold in math use the bm package and it's `\bm{...} ` command. It will give you bold italic on normal letters, bold on most symbols etc. Mathbf changes to an upright bold math font, textbf switches to an upright bold text font.

Answer (score 9):

`\emph` is defined to be a "text command" and therefore sets its argument in text mode. That's why you're allowed to use

```
$\emph{\bfseries <stuff>}$
```

since `\bfseries` occurs within text mode. The other way around,

```
$\bfseries\emph{<stuff>}$
```

`\bfseries` occurs inside math mode, which is not allowed.

If you want to set text in **bold** inside math, consider using `\textbf{<stuff>}` or `\text{\bfseries <stuff>}` if you're using [`amsmath`](//ctan.org/pkg/amsmath). If you want **bold** math content, you can use `\mathbf`. Alternatively, if you want ***bold italic*** math content, use `$\bm{<stuff>}$` and also add `\usepackage{bm}` to your preamble.

Note how `\bfseries` is used above; there is no argument. That is, `{\bfseries ...}`, not `\bfseries{...}`.